# Relationship between Selenium, Webdriver, test-unit?

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, testunit

Could someone help by defining the relation between the following: Selenium, Webdriver and most importantly test-unit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship between Selenium and Test-Unit.

Selenium is the overall project which combines RC, WebDriver and Grid.

WebDriver is the newest and more stable piece in the project, allowing you automate a browser using much more stable so-called 'native events'.

TestUnit is simply a unit testing tool for Ruby. You write some tests using Ruby, run it using TestUnit, it verifies if your test passes or fails. You can use this to write Selenium tests.

This is mostly mentioned on the Selenium site:

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

Comment: I would say the first and second sentences contradict each other. WebDriver is a component of the Selenium project. That *is* a relationship.

Comment: Didn't mean that specifically - have edited to clear that up.

Comment: Not sure why I got voted down, this is a valid question especially for  people new to selenium, exporting tests from the Selenium IDE asks whether you would like to use "test-unit" or Rspec. However there is no area on the selenium website where its specifically explained. Yes it just works but sometimes thats not enough

Comment: @EvilTester, I would suspect people were annoyed you didn't show research efforts. Even if you had said "what are the differences? I have looked on the Selenium website, but it isn't clear enough", that would probably have solved it. However, hopefully it now makes sense. If it does not, let us know. :)

Comment: @Arran, thanks for the feedback I can see your point of view. I couldn't see the relationship because there wasn't one however selenium IDE export feature 'implied' in some respects that there was. Nevertheless my question was answered thanks for the help! (aggressive voting down can sometimes deter people from asking valid questions)